# Multiple Objective C bridging headers in IOS project target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have two targets in my application and a common bridging header for both targets. Lets call targets as A and B

I added a new objective c based third party framework into my project. However, I want to use it in target A only and do not want its reference in target B.

**OPTION 1 if it is possible** :
Create another bridging header with import statements of the added library header files. In build settings, add this new bridging header as additional bridging header for target A.

For target B, do not add.

So, is it possible to have multiple bridging headers for a target? If yes, interested to know how exactly to add the second bridging header.

**OPTION 2:**
Having two separate bridging header for target A and B. Target A would have the additonal imports for the new library in its bridging header. The bridging header for B would not have those imports. With option 2, in future if I add a new third party library which I want to use in both the targets, I would have to add the import statements in both. With OPTION 1 this would not be the case.

Thoughts on what is the best approcah?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

Create Separate bridging header for each Target.

Select Your Target -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler.

Edit `Objective-C Bridging Header` `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` with Separate Target's Bridging Header.